# How to cut a line after a phrase is found?

Tags: grep

I have a large text file full of websites visited by hosts. This is the format:

```
Host : Url
```

A lot of the urls look like this:

```
http://google.com/?aslkdfjasldkfjaskldfjalskdjfalksdfjalksdjfa;sdlkfjas;dklfjasdklfjasdklfjasdklfjJUSTABUNCHOFRANDOMSTUFFaslkdjfaslkdfjaklsdfjaklsdjfasdkfjasdfklj
```

And it is hard to see what the original website is. How can I use grep to only show this:

```
Host : http://google.com
```

I've been looking everywhere to cut a line after the delimiter ".com" and can't find a solution. Thank you for you help!

Bonus: I forgot about .net, .org, and the other extensions. This might be a more difficult problem than I thought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
grep -oP 'Host : http://[^/]+'
                        ^^^^
```

(All characters that's not slashes)

or if you want to specify `.com` :

```
grep -oP 'Host : http://.*?\.com'
```

Another solution :

```
cut -d'/' -f1-3
```

Comment: Is there a way I can just omit whats after .com on each line?

Comment: Don't forget to upvote/accept if the answer fit your needs. Check http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote and http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: You seem like a great and valuable user to this site, but sadly I do not have 15 rep, It will be my journey to find this post and upvote your answer when I do.